# Using the host network with docker-compose

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I'm trying to set up a container with two networks with `docker-compose`. I would like one of those networks to be the `host` network (ie: as if I was running `docker run --net=host`) and the other a user-defined network.

I tried this:

```
version: '3'

networks:
  test:
    driver: bridge
  host:
    external: true

services:
  helloworld:
    image: python:3.6-alpine
    networks:
      - test
      - host
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
      - NET_RAW
    ports:
      - 0.0.0.0:8080:8080
    command: sh -c "cd /tmp && python -m http.server 8080"
```

I'm getting this error:

```
$ docker-compose up
Removing blah_helloworld_1
Starting 8743618e8af4_blah_helloworld_1 ... error

ERROR: for 8743618e8af4_blah_helloworld_1  network-scoped alias is supported only for containers in user defined networks

ERROR: for helloworld  network-scoped alias is supported only for containers in user defined networks
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Comment: Well you could use [`network_mode`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode) property in the service. This is mutually exclusive with the `networks` property though. If you use the `network_mode: "host"` your service has access to the `test` network, without explicitly joining. What exactly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: @vstm Can you pls describe how to access `test` network if `network_mode: "host"` is enabled?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports):

- **target**: the port inside the container
- **published**: the publicly exposed port
- **protocol**: the port protocol (tcp or udp)
- **mode**: host for publishing a host port on each node, or ingress for a swarm mode port to be load balanced.

Example:

```
 ports:
   - target: 8080
     published: 8080
     protocol: tcp
     mode: host
```

Answer (score 1):

While `host` is listed in `docker network ls` it works very differently from other networks.

By default each container is isolated in its own separate network namespace. When a container is put in the "host" network (using `network_mode: host` with compose), the container simply stays in the host's network namespace.

A container cannot be in a bridge network (like `test`) and also be in the `host` network at the same time as that would require this container to simultaneously be both in the host's network namespace and have its own separate network namespace.